# Magento: IndexController load phtml file from another(inactive) template

Tags: php, magento, templates

I was wondering if it is possible to load phtml files from templates that aren't currently active. For example if you are using a template
(lets call it explate) *app/design/frontend/default/explate* and you want to add your own phtml files (so they can get loaded by controllers) without putting them into the explate/template folder instead putting them in your own template folder (to keep things organized and prevent accidently overriding other template files).

Comment: Can you use Magento’s built-in [theme fallback](http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes)?

Comment: Yes, but then I have to put my template files in the /base folder (if I understood it right) wich is exactly what I'd like to prevent. I want to keep my files seperate from the core magento files. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Technically, a copy of new templates you create (as opposed to overriding the out-of-the-box ones) should be placed in the base design package, and those won’t interfere with upgrading Magento. But I was asking more specifically with regard to the linked article about using the new `<theme><parent>` layout feature in 1.9+